# How to merge two items of the same name in the list in java?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Items in an arrayList can have the same name.
For example:

First item

Name:Apple

Quantity:2

Second Item

Name:Apple

Quantity:3

if two items with same name found,How do i merge them so that only 1 'Apple' appear in the list with a quantity of 5?

Comment: `items.stream().collect(toMap(Item::getName, i -> i, Item::merge))`

Comment: Rather than an ArrayList, consider using a `HashMap<String, Integer>1